# How to read a text file by skipping first and last line in a file

Tags: java, file

I wanted to read a file line by line and store it to a variable. But, I want to skip the first and last line and store it to variable. How to do that?

Kindly help with a Java code to achieve this.

Comment: Have you tried any code? Provide some and ask your problems about that code.

Comment: Skipping the first line is easy - just read it and drop it on the floor before starting any loop. To skip the last line, keep the most recently read line in a separate variable, and only add it to the result when you see it has a successor.

Answer (score 3):

In Java 7 or Java 8 :

```
List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("file.txt"));
if(!lines.isEmpty()) {
    lines.remove(0);
}
if(!lines.isEmpty()) {
    lines.remove(lines.size() - 1);
}
```

Remove the `if` conditions if you are certain the files contain at least 2 lines.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to use an `ArrayList` to read the full file:

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(new File(//Here the path of your file));

ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

while (s.hasNext())
{
    list.add(s.nextLine());
}
```

Now that you have stored all the lines of your file (as an `ArrayList` of `String`) you can operate with the data.

To operate with the data you just have to iterate through them by a loop:

```
for(int i = 1; i < list.size() - 1; i++)
{
      String line = list.get(i);
      System.out.println(line);
}
```

Look that I start on the position `1` and ends on the position `list.size() - 1` to avoid the first and the last line of the file.

If you want to store your first line and your last line you can do:

```
String firstLine, lastLine;
firstLine = list.get(0);
lastLine = list.get(list.size());
```

I expect it will be helpful for you!

Comment: Thanks a lot.. it worked....

Comment: @DariusJames I'm glad that it helps to you! And please mark it as accepted answer if you consider that it's the best answer. Thanks!